# Hide keyboard when no view has a focus

Tags: android, keyboard, focus

Is it possible to hide soft keyboard when `activity?.currentFocus` and other similar methods return `null`?

Comment: Here is a great answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17789187/14759470

Comment: Maybe my question is not complete. I used all possible solutions from So but none worked. The keyboard shows anyway after the bottom sheet dialog is closed. The dialog closes the keyboard `onDismiss`, but it pops up again once the dialog is closed. So I'm wondering what forces it to open?

Comment: Ok, I couldn't find the root cause and solved it by setting softInputMode to always hidden

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use focuschangelistners for your edittext fields like this:

```
 txtName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus) {
           hideKeyboard();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, but I get null when trying to get focused view and the keyboard is still shown

Comment: Actually on global view tree observer no focus change takes place. The global focus change listener is not triggered